# Apache PDFBox: Move the last page to first Page

Tags: java, apache, pdf

I'm writing a simple Java Application with Apache PDFBox.
I have a several PDFs where the last page is the index of the content in the previous pages.

I need the index (last page) became the first page of the PDF file.

Is it possible?

I've also discovered the http://itextpdf.com/ library that sound better than Apache PDFBox, but in this case i don't know if i can do the thing i need either

Or maybe i can use this: http://saaspose.com/docs/display/pdf/How+to+Move+Page+within+a+Pdf+Document+%28Java+SDK%29

Answer (score 6):

I am using PDFBox version 2.0.0. Here is how I move the last page to the first position:

```
public static PDDocument moveLastPageToFirst(PDDocument documentToRearrangePages) {
    PDPageTree allPages = documentToRearrangePages.getDocumentCatalog().getPages();
    if (allPages.getCount() > 1) {
        PDPage lastPage = allPages.get(allPages.getCount() - 1);
        allPages.remove(allPages.getCount() - 1);
        PDPage firstPage = allPages.get(0);
        allPages.insertBefore(lastPage, firstPage);
    }
    return documentToRearrangePages;
}
```

Comment: Current PDFBox versions are 1.8.13 and 2.0.7.

Comment: specifically needed when using **boxable**, library to build tables in PDF documents. Refer [link](https://github.com/dhorions/boxable)

Answer (score 5):

With PDFBox you can open the original PDF into a PDDocument, then use getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages() to get a list of of the pages. Rearrange the list in the order you want, and write out each page to the new documents.

```
        PDDocument newDoc = new PDDocument();
        PDDocument oldDoc = PDDocument.load (args[0]);
        List allPages = oldDoc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();

        // Code to rearrange the list goes here

        for ( int curPageCnt = 0; curPageCnt < allPages.size(); curPageCnt++ )
        {
            newDoc.addPage( ( PDPage )allPages.get ( curPageCnt ) );
        } // end for
```