# insert new page in middle of pdf using pdfbox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I'm using PDFbox for downloading PDF. I want to add some new page in the middle.

```
PDPage page = new PDPage();
pdoc.addPage(page);
```

This code inserts the new page at end of the PDF.
How can I insert a page at another position?

Comment: Where exactly are you having problems?  From your your question one can only see that you are asking for help.  You need to provide details about where you need help.

Answer (score 4):

When a PDF is created with PDF-Box the result of

```
doc.getDocumentCatalog().getPages().getKids();
```

is a flat list. It contains all pages in a sequence.

```
PDPageNode
|- Page1
|- Page2
|- Page3
```

If the PDF was not created with PDF-Box this might not be true, instead the PDPageNode for all Pages can be layed out in a tree structure

```
PDPageNode
|-Page1
|-PDPageNode
|  |- Page2
|  |- Page3
|- Page4
```

In this case the sample code mentioned in the other answer will not work. Instead you can use the following

```
public void addPage(PDDocument doc, final int index, final PDRectangle size) {
    // Use the normal method if the page comes after all other pages
    if (index >= doc.getNumberOfPages())
        doc.addPage(new PDPage(size));
    else {
        final PDPage page = new PDPage(size);

        // Find the existing page that is currently at the index
        // the new page will be
        final PDPage nextPage = (PDPage) doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get(index);

        // Get the node the current page is stored in
        PDPageNode pageNode = nextPage.getParent();

        // Set the appropriate node as the new pages parent
        page.setParent(pageNode);

        // Insert the new page in the node at the index of the current page is stored
        // this shifts all pages in the node forward
        pageNode.getKids().add(pageNode.getKids().indexOf(nextPage), page);

        // Update the current node and all parent nodes
        while (pageNode != null) {
            pageNode.updateCount();
            pageNode = pageNode.getParent();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add your page before another page with:

```
PDPageTree pages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getPages();
pages.insertBefore(page, pages.get(0));  //0 - index of the page before that you wish to add your new page
```

or after another page with:

```
PDPageTree pages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getPages();
pages.insertAfter(page, pages.get(0));  //0 index of the page after that you wish to add your new page
```

Tested with PDFBox v2.0.21

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will be helpful:
[Apache PDFBox: Move the last page to first Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225080/apache-pdfbox-move-the-last-page-to-first-page)

It seems that you can't insert page directly so you have to rearrange the list.

You could also try

```
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load( file );
// Open this pdf to edit. 
PDPage page = new PDPage(); 
PDPageNode rootPages = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getPages();
rootPages.getKids().add(100, page ); 
//Write some text page.setParent( rootPages ); 
rootPages.updateCount(); 
doc.save( file );
doc.close();
```

but this seem to work only with pdf created by pdfbox.

Comment: thank you for response . Can you explain in detail how your code will work,as i am new for pdfbox.

Comment: *this seem to work only with pdf created by pdfbox* - The pages in a PDF are organized in a *page tree* with the actual pages being the leafs. Your `rootPages` node is the *root* of that tree. Only in case of a flat structure (all pages being direct kids of this tree root node), you succeed with your code.